# AWS elastic beanstalk initialization error while deploying Django app

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to install the awsebscli package in my virtualenv, first trying  the below command

```
pip install awsebcli
```

then the next command that initializes eb

```
eb init
```

then when I choose a region number from the given list, it says the following error given below.

> UnicodeDecodeError: ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 20:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

This error shows up when I am selecting the region using its number.

Comment: This is a bug. My guess is you have a weird character in your application name. Can you rerun `eb init` with the `--debug` option and include the output in your question?

Comment: thanks for your comment@NickHumrich..am attaching the screenshot of the  debug info and the error message i got.

Comment: I don't see anything added.

Comment: @sabareesh Don't attach a screenshot, paste the actual output.